# Union null in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, union

I'm trying to combine 2 querys in oracle, those lines have the same value expect one field.

Ex:

```
SELECT NAME, AGE, EMAIL, DATE FROM table_a WHERE NAME = 'JOAO' AND FLAG = '0'
UNION
SELECT NAME, AGE, EMAIL, DATE FROM table_a WHERE NAME = 'JOAO' AND FLAG = '1'
```

Result:

```
NAME   AGE   EMAIL      DATE   
JOAO   23    a@a.com    20150414
JOAO   23    a@a.com    null
```

How i can group this lines?? I'm looking for something who can give me something like this result:

```
NAME   AGE   EMAIL      DATE   
JOAO   23    a@a.com    20150414
```

Thank you
(sorry for my english..)

Comment: Is DATE always NULL if FLAG is 1?

Comment: Why arent you using just the data row only with FLAG = 0? why do you need the other row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use COALESCE(). http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm#SQLRF00617/ms190349.aspx

This Query should work for every name, and should coalesce the other rows.

```
SELECT 
    NAME1 AS NAME,
    COALESCE(AGE1, AGE2) AS AGE,
    COALESCE(EMAIL1, EMAIL2) AS EMAIL,
    COALESCE(DATE1, DATE2) AS DATE
FROM(
    SELECT 
        t1.NAME AS NAME1, 
        t1.AGE AS AGE1, 
        t1.EMAIL AS EMAIL1, 
        t1.DATE AS DATE1,
        t2.NAME AS NAME2, 
        t2.AGE AS AGE2, 
        t2.EMAIL AS EMAIL2, 
        t2.DATE AS DATE2 
    FROM table_a AS t1
    INNER JOIN table_a AS t2
    ON t2.FLAG = 1 AND t1.FLAG = 0 AND t1.NAME = t2.NAME
) AS t3;
```

Comment: Since he has flagged this as Oracle, it might help to point to the Oracle doc, not the SQL server docs ;) :    http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions030.htm#SQLRF00617   (they are the same, in this case, so "meh" ) :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to ignore the NULL values:

```
  SELECT NAME, AGE, EMAIL, DATE 
    FROM table_a 
   WHERE NAME = 'JOAO' 
     AND FLAG in ( '0', '1' )
     and date is not null
  /
```

or
if you want to keep the nulls, but defer to available non-null values:

```
  with w_data as (
        SELECT NAME, AGE, EMAIL, DATE ,
               row_number() over ( partition by name
                             order by date desc nulls last ) rnum
          FROM table_a 
         WHERE NAME = 'JOAO' 
           AND FLAG in ( '0', '1' )
     )
  select name, age, email, date
    from w_data
   where rnum = 1
  /
```

[edit]
in response to comment:

If you want to keep union, that's fine, union and OR are mostly interchangeable (in this case):

```
  SELECT NAME, AGE, EMAIL, DATE 
    FROM table_a 
   WHERE NAME = 'JOAO' 
     AND FLAG = '0'
     and date is not null
     union
  SELECT NAME, AGE, EMAIL, DATE 
    FROM table_a 
   WHERE NAME = 'JOAO' 
     AND FLAG = '1'
     and date is not null
  /
```

or even:

```
  select * from (
  SELECT NAME, AGE, EMAIL, DATE 
    FROM table_a 
   WHERE NAME = 'JOAO' 
     AND FLAG = '0'
   union
  SELECT NAME, AGE, EMAIL, DATE 
    FROM table_a 
   WHERE NAME = 'JOAO' 
     AND FLAG = '1'
  )
  where date is not null
  /
```

if you just want the NULL criteria in 1 place ;)
Same logic can apply to the 2nd query I wrote above using row_number() analytics ...

```
  with w_data as (
     SELECT NAME, AGE, EMAIL, DATE 
       FROM table_a 
      WHERE NAME = 'JOAO' 
        AND FLAG = '0'
      union
     SELECT NAME, AGE, EMAIL, DATE 
       FROM table_a 
      WHERE NAME = 'JOAO' 
        AND FLAG = '1'
     ),
     w_sub as ( 
        select name, age, email, date,
              row_number() over ( partition by name
                             order by date desc nulls last ) rnum
          from w_data
       )
  select name, age, email, date
    from w_sub
   where rnum = 1
  /
```

Comment: Ditto... unfortunelly i need use 2 selects in that case... the system that i'm using able me to set the 2 selects and he will made the union... =/ that is a big problem but thank you for you help

Comment: Fine, but which of the above is the case? do you want to ignore all NULL values? or just prefer non-NULL over NULL ... using NULLs if they are the only ones ?

Answer (score 0):

It would be the case to change your conditions in the 'WHERE' clause from

```
WHERE NAME = 'JOAO' AND FLAG = '0'
```

to

```
WHERE NAME = 'JOAO' AND FLAG IN('0','1')
```

so your selection shows all the registers with either '0' or '1' values for the column 'FLAG'.

Comment: In that case (ex) i realy need use 2 selects.. The system that i'm using in my job is a ¨%#$